# Delete data in source once data has been pushed to kafka server

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using confluent platform 3.3 to pull data from Oracle database. Once the data has been pushed to kafka server the retrieved data should be deleted in the database.

Are there any way to do it ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default way of doing this with Kafka.

How are you reading your data from the database, using Kafka Connect, or with custom code that you wrote?

If the latter is the case I'd suggest implementing the delete in your code, collect ids once Kafka has confirmed send and batch delete regularly.

Alternatively you could write a small job that reads your Kafka topic with a different consumer group than your actual target system and deletes based on the records it pulls from the topic. If you run this job every few minutes, hours,... you can keep up with the sent data as well.

Comment: I'm using Kafka connect and may I know whether it has a configuration to delete. I searched a lot but didn't find a solution .

Comment: The jdbc connector has no option to delete records after having read them, no. It should not be too hard to implement as a PR, if you are interested..